# want to create react app offline becoz online creating time and internet consuming

Tags: reactjs

can react app can be created offline because I cant get access to internet every time and it takes too much time. is there any way I can create app using offline method. I know the NPX use internet and NPM use to install globally. But I am confused . can anyone help me?

Comment: if i want to create app without using internet how to do it?

Comment: I don't fully understand what you meant. To be able to use React you have to download dependencies and you will need internet for that, but usually it's a couple megabytes. It could work offline if you don't need to call the backend API

Comment: just install dependencies when you have internet and you will be able to use it when you are offline

Comment: if we create-react-app globally so we dont require internet to create as many app we want in future?

Comment: yes, but also you could install it locally, as usual, and just copy paste your project folder with node_modules

Comment: just usually it's not enough to have react in dependencies, in most cases you will need more dependencies